# ManyToMany field as an argument to .objects.create() function

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, view, models

I have 2 classes, `Design` and `Order`. I`m trying to create an Order object in my views.py and I want to give the Design object as the argument for .objects.create() 
when I do that, I get this error: " 'design' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"
I think this is because Design is a ManyToMany field in my Order model. and idea what should I do?
thanks a million.
models.py:

```
class Design(models.Model):
    dimension=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    number_of_colors=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sides=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='side(s)')

class Order(models.Model):
    o_type=models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Order type', null=True)
    number=models.IntegerField()
    date=models.DateField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    design=models.ManyToManyField(Design)
    outSource=models.OneToOneField(OutSource, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print "entered upload"
        image=request.FILES.get('upload', False)
        sides=request.POST.get('sides', False)
        number=request.POST.get('number', False)
        design=Design.objects.create(image=image, sides=sides)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        customer=Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        order=Order.objects.create(customer=customer, date=now, number=number, design=design)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
```

Comment: Have you tried `order = Order(design=design,...)`?

Comment: try using order.design.add(design). you cannot pass it in create()

Comment: @AjayGupta thank you for helping. you`re right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add a `ManytoManyField` in `create` because `ManyToManyField`s involve intermediate tables for database queries.

You'll need two queries for it:

```
order=Order.objects.create(customer=customer, date=now, number=number)
order.design.add(design)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Leistungsabfall . problem solved :)